# Accessing the Program Segment Prefix

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

I'm trying to access the Program Segment Prefix (PSP) in x86 MASM Assembler. As a test, I'd like to print the given command line arguments after running my program. I tried putting the address of the PSP in the `dx` register, with an offset of `81h`: the position of the command line arguments.

However, after running the program, I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0WIm.png) in return. I can see the given command line argument, but it is preceded by a lot of gibberish. Any idea why this is happening? I guess I'm not correctly accessing the PSP at 81h?

```
IDEAL
P386
MODEL FLAT, C
ASSUME cs:_TEXT,ds:FLAT,es:FLAT,fs:FLAT,gs:FLAT

CODESEG

start:

        sti                 ; Set The Interrupt Flag
        cld                 ; Clear The Direction Flag

        push ds             ; Put value of DS register on the stack
        pop es              ; And write this value to ES

        mov ah, 09h
        mov dx, ds:[81h]
        int 21h

        mov eax, 4c00h      ; AH = 4Ch - Exit To DOS
        int 21h             ; DOS INT 21h

DATASEG

STACK 1000h

END start
```

Comment: @zx485 Yes, it is a continuation of my first question. I learned some new things and I got a bit further in trying to access these command line arguments, but stumbled upon a new problem.

Comment: What was the sample argument that gave you that output (i.e. what command line did you run your program with?)

Comment: I ran my program with the argument `commandlineargument`. You can see the argument printed as the last string on the screen.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect it's because INT 21h subfunction 9 requires '$' to terminate string.

Also, I think `mov dx, ds:[81h]` should be `mov dx, 81h` since the DS is already loaded as required by the interrupt.

Consider something like:

```
IDEAL
P386
MODEL FLAT, C
ASSUME cs:_TEXT,ds:FLAT,es:FLAT,fs:FLAT,gs:FLAT

CODESEG

start:

        sti                 ; Set The Interrupt Flag
        cld                 ; Clear The Direction Flag

        push ds             ; Put value of DS register on the stack
        pop es              ; And write this value to ES

        ; INT 21h subfunction 9 requires '$' to terminate string
        xor   bx, bx
        mov   bl, [80h]
        cmp   bl, 126
        ja    exit
        mov   byte [bx + 81h], '$'

        ; print the string
        mov   ah, 09h
        mov   dx, 81h
        int   21h

exit:

        mov eax, 4c00h      ; AH = 4Ch - Exit To DOS
        int 21h             ; DOS INT 21h

DATASEG

STACK 1000h

END start
```

This is a useful resource for interrupt APIs:

http://spike.scu.edu.au/~barry/interrupts.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @Donald_W. Unfortunately, when running the code with a command line argument, I get nothing in return.

Comment: Also, it didn't want to compile because it complained about the `byte` keyword in the `mov` instruction. It compiled fine after removing `byte` though.

Comment: What compiler / environment are you using?

Comment: I'm using DOSBox + a set of DOS tools (Assembler, Linker, Debugger). I'm using Open Watcom.

Comment: @pvdsp Are you trying to build a native 16-bit DOS executable or 32-bit DOS extended executable?  The `MODEL FLAT` directive indicates the later, and how you would access the PSP would be much different in 32-bit protected mode.

Comment: @Ross Ridge how would I access the PSP in 32-bit? Didn't realize it would be different.

Comment: @pvdsp I dunno, it probably depends on the particular DOS extender you're using.