# Read command-line arguments from the Program Segment Prefix in 8086 Assembly

Tags: assembly, masm, x86-16

I am writing my first assembler program using 16-bit 8086 Assembly (MASM 5.00 in a DOSBox).

I am trying to read the command-line arguments from the PSP [as suggested in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45743751/accessing-the-program-segment-prefix):

```
sti
cld
push ds
pop es

mov ah,09h
mov dx,81h
int 21h
```

This will print the command line arguments if I end them with a `$`, so:

`test param1 param2 param3$`

will print

`param1 param2 param3`

I tried to terminate the string by putting the `$` sign in memory with

```
xor bx,bx
mov bl,[80h]
mov byte [bx + 81h],'$'
```

but the last line results in `error A2011: Type illegal in context`. Am I getting the syntax wrong here?

My next goal would be to split the argument string and store each argument separately for later use (some of the arguments are numerical so I will need to convert them as well but I have some ideas on how to achieve that).

Are there any good examples on how to do this? The resources I found so far either target different CPU architectures or use standard libraries.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `mov [bx + 81h], byte '$'`?  I'm not super familiar with MASM.

Comment: I'd've thought `mov byte ptr [bx + 81h],'$'`.

Comment: As for splitting the args, you'll need some memory to write the values into.  You can either allocate some fixed size buffers using `db`, or ask the OS for some with [this](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/4901).

Comment: `mov byte ptr [81h + bx],'$'` works, thank you David!

Comment: My other mistake was writing `80h` into `bl` instead of the value at memory address `80h`. This works as expected: `xor bx, bx`, `mov bl, byte ptr es:[80h]`, `mov byte ptr [81h + bx],'$'`

Comment: When you'll  need to parse cmdline arguments, you may find an inspiration at https://euroassembler.eu/maclib/dosapi.htm#GetArg

Comment: Still pretty terrible code but I got my first 8086 assembler program working: https://github.com/martinschneider/juvavum/blob/master/asm/8086/board.asm. Thanks, everyone for their help!